# ImageButton events on Nested Masterpage in dynamic usercontrol not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have found many equivalent questions here, but non seem to apply to my problem.

I am dynamically loading controls into a Nested Masterpage. The button click event is not firing for buttons in different usercontrols, loaded in the Nested Masterpage.

When debugging, it seems like just a normal postback that occurs when a any button is clicked on the nested masterpage. No events are fired / caught in debug. The nested masterpage re-loads (post back), and that is about it.

Some Info that might pertain to the situation:

- I am using codebehind for my methods, and where I expect to catch the event.
- I have put the code that loads the uc's in the Nested MasterPage's init sub.
- I have tested, and adding the control to the panel manually, everything is wired up as expected, throughout the lifecycle, and events are fired for the manually added control.
- I have tested with using a static client ID for my buttons, as I thought the event might be wired up incorrectly. This did not have any effect.
- I have manually assigned unique id's to my controls, no effect.
- All usercontrol have and keep the correct properties set for them (Description, Quantity etc.).
- I am reloading the usercontrols every time the nested masterpage loads.
- I am not exiting on ifIsPostback, but instead reloading controls on every postback, as one of the buttons on the controls, might remove that control, and the new remaining controls need to be rebuilt on Page Init of the masterpage.
- There is a script manager on the Master Page (not the nested masterpage).
- I am making use of Ajax in the content pages, but not in the Nester Masterpage.
- There is no update panel on the masterpage or nested masterpage.
- All events are firing in a normal fashion on the content pages.
- From my content pages, I remove and add controls to the nested masterpage dynamically. This works well and controls are loaded accordingly.
- I am not setting the controls from the content page to the masterpage directly.
- I am creating controls in my content pages, and pass them to a routine that manages a custom object containing all my controls, add and removing controls form this object as necessary.
- In my Nested Masterpage Init event, I step through my custom controls
  object and add them to a panel.
- I am not sure how to debug the postback event in the browser, as I am
  not making use of an udpate panel and Ajax for these controls in the
  Nested Masterpage.

Here is the generated HTML for the Control that works (Manually dropped in at design time)

```
<input type="image" src="bookings_media/buttons/add-another-unit.jpg" 
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAddAnotherUnit1_butAddAnotherUnit" 
name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucAddAnotherUnit1$butAddAnotherUnit">
```

This is the rendered HTML for the dynamically added control:

```
<input type="image" src="bookings_media/buttons/add-another-unit.jpg" 
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_butAddAnotherUnit"
name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$butAddAnotherUnit">
```

Any ideas what might be snagging here:

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnCommand instead of OnClick regarding the ImageButton.

Comment: I am not using markup OnClick, I am using code behind. Nevertheless, I have tried using the _command event codebehind, and event is not caught.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue once. Do you recreate your usercontrols on postback?

Comment: I add them to the panel on the masterpage every time the page either posts back, or loads.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I updated the question with more detail.